# Horizontally and vertically centered cells except the second column

Tags: tables

I want my all cells have horizontally and vertically centered except second column. I want my second column only vertically centered, but the alignment is on the left.

My attempt:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|p{4cm}|}
    \hline
    No. & $f(t)$ & $F(s)$\\
    \hline
    1. & Fungsi tangga konstan, $f(t)=1$ & $$\frac 1s;\, s>0$$\\
    \hline
    2. & Fungsi identitas, $f(t)=t$ & $$\frac 1{s^2};\, s>0$$\\
    \hline
    3. & Fungsi eksponensial, $f(t)=1$ & $$\frac 1s;\, s>0$$\\
    \hline
    4. & Fungsi tangga konstan, $f(t)=e^{-\omega t}$ & $$\frac 1{s+\omega};\, s>0$$\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Can you help me? I've seen my possible duplicate, but seems like there is an error when I'm using `\usepackage{ragged2e}`. And I want the width to fit the text length naturally. For example, the first column has a smaller width.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{|c|l|m{4cm}|}` should result in the desired alignment.

Comment: @leandriis it's error.

Comment: Did you load the `array` package? The `m` column type is only available when the `array` package is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To vertically centre cells contents, you can use the `cellspace` package, which ensures a *minimal* vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (unfortunately already used by `siunitx`), or any letter you want with the loading option `column=`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{5pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|>{$\displaystyle}Oc<{$}|}
    \hline
    No. & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$f(t)$} & F(s)\\
    \hline
    1. & Fungsi tangga konstan, $f(t)=1$ & \frac 1s;\, s>0 \\
    \hline
    2. & Fungsi identitas, $f(t)=t$ & \frac 1{s²};\, s>0 \\
    \hline
    3. & Fungsi eksponensial, $f(t)=1$ & \frac 1s;\, s>0 \\
    \hline
    4. & Fungsi tangga konstan, $f(t)=e^{-ωt}$ & \frac 1{s+ω};\, s>0 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, i really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, can i have a last question please? My last problem is the header of the table. I want them all to centered but won't affect the other cells. (the second column of the header still on the left)

Comment: Use `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{$f(t)$}` for the head of the 2nd column.

Comment: @Bernard: I think that there is a slight mistake in your comment. It should be `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{$f(t)$}`.

Comment: @F.Pantigny: You're right. One of my many *lapsus calami*…

Answer (score 1):

Centering both for `horz` and `vert` -- I think you will make out the difference and be able to do the rest-- if not please revert

[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{
        |
                    >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in}% instead of "p" is "m"
        |
                    >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in}% instead of "p" is "m"
        |
                    >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in}% instead of "p" is "m"
        |}
    \hline
    No. & $f(t)$ & $F(s)$\\
    \hline
    1. & Fungsi tangga konstan, $f(t)=1$ & $$\frac 1s;\, s>0$$\\
    \hline
    2. & Fungsi identitas, $f(t)=t$ & $$\frac 1{s^2};\, s>0$$\\
    \hline
    3. & Fungsi eksponensial, $f(t)=1$ & $$\frac 1s;\, s>0$$\\
    \hline
    4. & Fungsi tangga konstan, $f(t)=e^{-\omega t}$ & $$\frac 1{s+\omega};\, s>0$$\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, i really appreciate it.